# Fading flashing button with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, animation

I need some help please with AngularJS/Bootstrap to be enable me to have a smooth fade based flashing button (Don't want a simple "on/off") ... I need to highlight to the user that they need to press submit.

I've done lots of searching for this and there's examples of fading one panel out and another one in... but there doesn't seem to be a simple version just to "flash" some text.

My apologies but I know my information in my question is a bit thin on "content" but I am fairly new to Angular (I only know the basic constructs) and just have no real clue where to start.

TYIA

Comment: Hello. Check ng-animate: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngAnimate

Comment: Thanks @Kędrzu - I did look at that but the example is based on the user clicking a button to fade in/out... I just need it to permanently fade in/out

Comment: This is entirerly made on css animations. Look, that animation is based on scope variable. Clicking a button only changes it. See this animation generator: https://coveloping.com/tools/css-animation-generator There is a great choice of possible css animations.

Comment: @Kędrzu - Brilliant... Worked a treat... Thanks... (please add as an answer so I can upvote and accept)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by using `ng-animate`. Check [this documentation for ng-animate](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngAnimate). Basically it is all about css animations.

If you need any help in creating such css animation classes, refer to [this css animation generator](https://coveloping.com/tools/css-animation-generator).